# Wordpress - How to get the small size thumbnail image inside the loop

Tags: wordpress

I am creating a new theme from scrath. The blog page is index.php.
I also made a search in other cases, and tried different solutions other than those I report here below, but nothing seems to work.

I have the following in the loop:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>"><img class="post-image" itemprop="image" src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)); ?>">
```

That works fine but gives the full sized image.

If I change it to:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>"><img class="post-image" itemprop="image" src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail'); ?>">
```

Nothing changes. Still gives the full size image.

I tried to following [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/) to get the url inside the loop in this way:

```
echo 'aaaaa' . get_the_post_thumbnail_url('thumbnail'); 
echo 'aaaaa' . get_the_post_thumbnail_url('thumbnail');
```

But in both cases it renders only "aaaaa". No url returned.

Here is the full loop:

```
    <?php
    $mtw_the_excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
    $mtw_headline = substr($mtw_the_excerpt, 0, 100) . '...';
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
        echo 'aaaaa' . get_the_post_thumbnail_url('thumbnail');                 
        ?>
        <article class="blog-post-in-loop" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
            <meta itemprop="author" content="<?php echo get_bloginfo(); ?>">
            <meta itemprop="headline" content="<?php echo $mtw_headline; ?>">
            <link itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" />
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>"><img class="post-image" itemprop="image" src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail'); ?>"></a>

            <div class="date">
                <time class="date_month" datetime="<?php the_time('c') ?>" itemprop="datePublished"><?php echo get_the_date('m'); ?></time>
                <time class="date_year"><?php echo get_the_date('Y'); ?></time>
                <time datetime="<?php the_modified_date('c') ?>" itemprop="dateModified"></time>
            </div>
            <div class="title-exceprt-and-read-more">
                <h1 class='blogpost_title' itemprop="name"><a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></a></h1>
                <p class='post-excerpt'><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                <div class='read-more'><a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>"><?php _e('Czytaj więcej','mtw-translation'); ?></a></div>
            </div>
            <div itemprop="publisher" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Organization">
                <div itemprop="logo" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
                    <meta itemprop="url" content="https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/logo.jpg">
                    <meta itemprop="width" content="523">
                    <meta itemprop="height" content="188">
                </div>
                <meta itemprop="name" content="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>">
            </div>
        </article>
    <?php
    endwhile;
    ?>
```

Can anyone point me out to what is wrong and kindly support me with a solution?

Comment: Did you register `add_theme_support('post-thumbnail')`?

Answer (score 0):

Great that you are coding a theme from scratch! Tip: always refer to [Wordpress Developer Resources](https://developer.wordpress.org/) when using its functions.

So the function [get_the_post_thumbnail_url](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/) as per Wordpress Documentation receives 2 parameters:

> get_the_post_thumbnail_url( int|WP_Post $post = null, string|array
>   $size = 'post-thumbnail' )

The first parameter should be the Post ID, Post object or Null (if it is inside the loop)

Try:

```
echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(), 'thumbnail');
```

Or simply:

```
echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url();
```